Find average of a range from 2 Excel columns
I have datasets in 2 columns .
Column A has numbers 0 to 50.
Column B has percentages.
Looking to find % average by a range from column A.
e.g : % average from column B of dataset 0-10 from column A
Thank you

Try using the following formula:
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">=0",A:A,"<=10")


Or, Using FILTER() function:
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B:B,(A:A>=0)*(A:A<=10)))


